# Datebox CustomConstraint

Tags: java, zk

Datebox has the nice feature that, by using pure String constraints like "no past", "no future", etc. you can limit the values that can be picked from the chooser dialog. If you put "no past" there, no past values are available.

```
constraint="no past"
```

or...

```
myDatebox.setConstraint("no past");
```

Unfortunately, you can of course still enter past values manually as text.

Since I use a different way to handle errors there, how can I combine CustomConstraint (to show my errors in a custom way) with the simple String constraint, so that I get the disabled fields in the date picker plus custom error handling?

Simply creating my own...

```
class InternalDateConstraint extends SimpleConstraint implements CustomConstraint {...
```

...doesn't work. It seems that the limiting of available dates in the picker only happens when you directly give a String, not a Constraint object.Using that with "no past" in the constructor does NOT limit the values you can choose, it only gives an error message if you chose wrong...

Any idea here. In the end, I simply need something like...

```
datebox.setEarliestDataToChooseFromPicker( TODAY );
```

Answer (score 0):

The datebox constraint has also before and after.
Like this you could set a min and max date. It ssupport databinding, so creating the constraint in VM is also possible.
You van also give a custom message in this way,:

```
no past:'I said no past!!!!!!'
```

Comment: The problem is not the text of the message, the problem is how the message is displayed - in a popup box next to the message, which is completely different from what I need. With a CustomConstraint, I could fix that, no problem, but not with a SimpleConstraint, it seems.